# How to relaunch package configuration on libnss-ldap reinstallation

Tags: package-management, ldap

I've removed the file `/etc/ldap.conf` which was used by `libnss-ldap`.

Later I wanted to restore it by completely removing the package with

```
apt get remove libnss-ldap
```

and installing it again. But with second installation there was no configuration setup.

[image: configuration setup]

How can I reconfigure the package in order to get a fresh `/etc/ldap.conf` file? And how to launch this package configuration. Why it's only on first install?

Comment: That command you describe there is incorrect. Did you mean `apt-get remove libnss-ldap`?

Comment: @ByteCommander yeah you're right. I've removed libnss-ldap succesfully, but have problem that on reinstalling there's no configuration prompt.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge libnss-ldap` and `sudo apt-get install libnss-ldap`. Purge also removes global configuration, which is retained if you only remove. You could also try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libnss-ldap`.

Comment: @ByteCommander's tip worked for me!

Comment: Still not anothing better than purge and reinstall? Dpkg-reconfigure does not re-prompt the menu shown by OP.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
dpkg-reconfigure ldap-auth-config
```

Comment: Please explain why you think that this will help!

Comment: I bumped into this thread by having the same issue. I wanted to launch the wizard second time.  Eventually I found this command that do the job so decided to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
dpkg-reconfigure libnss-ldapd
```